# Http requests with id (put, delete) don't work in ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, httprequest, asp.net-core-8

I'm developing a Rest API and I'm faced with a situation that I don't understand now. Http requests with id (put, delete) do not work. I get a 404 error in Postman. Thanks for the help.

Controller and method routing:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
```

```
    [HttpPut("/update/{id}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateUser(int id, [FromBody] UserModel userModel)
    {
        if (userModel != null)
        {
            var existingUser = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);

            if (existingUser != null)
            {
                existingUser.FirstName = userModel.FirstName;
                existingUser.LastName = userModel.LastName;
                existingUser.Email = userModel.Email;
                existingUser.Password = userModel.Password;
                existingUser.Phone = userModel.Phone;
                existingUser.Photo = userModel.Photo;
                existingUser.Status = userModel.Status;

                _db.Users.Update(existingUser);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                return Ok();
            }

            return NotFound();
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
```

I also tried another variant of routing but requests do not work too:

```
    [HttpPut("/{id}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateUser(int id, [FromBody] UserModel userModel)
```

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKhKD.png)

Comment: Since you also throw a 404 (return NotFound()) in code it could be you, but have you tried debugging this? Do you have the correct method (PUT) in PostMan? Are you sure you're hitting your endpoint? Have you tried a HttpGet first and if so, does this work?

Comment: The question's code is using absolute paths, thus *causing* the 404. Right now the first `UpdateUser` is listening for PUT on `http://mysite/update/45`, not `http://mysite/Users/update/45` while the second is listening for PUT on `http://mysite/45`. There's no need to specify explicit paths as long as naming and routing conventions are followed. The code in [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) rarely uses explicit paths, except for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0):

> I'm developing a Rest API and I'm faced with a situation that I don't
> understand now. Http requests with id (put, delete) do not work. I get
> a 404 error in Postman.

Well according to your shared code snippet, while you would define your API action with `HttpPut("/update/{id}")]` your route no more remain like `/api/users/update/50` instead it becomes like `https://localhost:7299/update/50`.

Which defines a fixed path "/update/" with an ID placeholder `({id})`. As a result you are getting 404 no matter its `/api/users/update/50` or `/api/update/50`

[image]

[image]

Solution:

Now the main question how you would like to have your route endpoint? If you want your route like `https://localhost:7299/api/users/update/50` then you should refactor your controller action as following:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPut("update/{id}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateUser(int id, [FromBody] UserModel userModel)
    {

       
    }

}
```

**Note:** Above modification would restore your endpoint route as `https://localhost:7299/api/users/update/50`

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) if you want to study more.